# Change in distribution of a portfolio of customers

Tags: time-series, clustering, business-intelligence

I'm looking for some high-level thoughts on understanding a change in distribution for a portfolio of customers.

I have a file with information on a bunch of customers. These customers are purchasing some financial product (credit cards, loans, etc.). The file has information on the customer (age, gender, etc.)

Over the course of a year, some customers leave while others are added. I'm trying to come up with profiles of customers who leave and profiles of customers who stay. Specifically, I'd like to understand the change in distribution of the customer base from one year to another.

What statistical processes are useful for this type of analysis? I'm looking for something deeper than just "last year, X% of customers were age 25 and younger while this year its Y%". I'm more interested in being able to classify the customers into segments and saying which of the segments grew and which shrank.